# several ediff sessions in one emacs

Tags: ediff

f.e. I want to compare 2 pair of files
file1 vs file11
file2 vs file22
For now I run the bash `for`, loop over 2 file pairs and run emacs 2 times. But it is not so convenient because I can not go back.
Is it possible to run emacs with a list of file pairs which will open several ediff sessions where I'll be able to switch between them?

Comment: Why not?  You can have any number of Ediff sessions active at the same time.